# node.js распаковка бинарных данных

Tags: node.js, binary

Дано:

```
c2bb765a Бинарные данные представленный ввиде шестнадцатиричных Big-Endian (Network)
```

Ожидаемуй результат:

```
-93.731155395508
```

Код:

```
let hexToBinary = require('hex-to-binary');
let pack = require('jspack');

console.log(pack.jspack.Unpack("!f", hexToBinary('c2bb765a')));
```

Текущий результат:

```
4.814825477265672e-26
```

Библиотека распаковки значения не имеет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужны никакие дополнительные пакеты. В nodejs уже всё есть:

```
let b = Buffer.from('c2bb765a', 'hex');
console.log(b.readFloatBE(0));
// -93.73115539550781
```

https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html